# Cannot set promiscuous mode in windows 10 using python socket api function socket.ioctl()

Tags: python, windows, sockets, packet-sniffers, promiscuous-mode

i have the following code :

```
import socket

sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_IP)
sniffer.bind(("",0))
sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL,socket.RCVALL_ON)
data = sniffer.recvfrom(65535)
print(f"RECVD : {data}")
sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL,socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

in which ,I try to enable promiscuous in windows in the line

```
sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL,socket.RCVALL_ON)
```

but when I run the code, I get the following OSError:

[WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

Just a quick note: I am running the code via a privileged shell.

PS : please excuse me if this question has been asked in some implicit form by someone else earlier, as I have done my part and did not find anythin relevant

Comment: Which branch does the first `if` clause take? Can you please remove everything that's not not part of an [mcve]?

Comment: please check the updated version

Comment: how long should I wait before I stop expecting the answer?Pls help me guys. This feels like a really easy one to solve